# Apply a function to all exports of an object and export using the same name

Tags: typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I'm not sure how to explain this but here is what I'm trying to do:

**LoginDispatch.ts**

```
const useLoginDispatch = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const setLoginScreen = (screen: LoginScreen) => {
    dispatch(loginActions.setLoginScreen(screen))
  }

  const setRegisterError = (message: string) => {
    dispatch(loginActions.setRegisterError(message))
  }

  // This is a lot of code to write just to dispatch() each action, I would need 
  // to do this hundreds of times
  // Can I automate this process?
  // Notice how the exports below have the same name as the loginActions exports

  return { setLoginScreen , setRegisterError}
}
```

All I'm doing is applying `dispatch()` to every exported function from `loginActions`. To change the login screen of my app I can type:

**LoginComponent.tsx**

```
const loginDispatch = useLoginDispatch()
loginDispatch.setLoginScreen(LoginScreen.Register)
```

And not:

**LoginComponent.tsx**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(loginActions.setRegisterError(message))
```

Now I can continue manually adding functions to **LoginDispatch.ts** like I am already, but I have hundreds of Actions in my application. Is there a way I can automatically map `dispatch` to all the exports in **LoginActions.ts** and export them using their original function name.

Here's my Actions.ts file if you would like to see. (Every export is structured the same, except for the parameters and the return type of course)

**Actions.ts**

```
export const setLoginScreen = (screen: LoginScreen): LoginActionTypes => ({
  type: LoginActions.SET_LOGIN_SCREEN,
  payload: screen
})

export const setRegisterError = (message: string): LoginActionTypes => ({
  type: LoginActions.SET_REGISTER_ERROR,
  payload: message
})
```

**NOTE:** I am keeping **Actions.ts** the same, because I have other functions (in sagas) like put(), which also call to these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
const useLoginDispatch = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //memoize the result with useMemo (create only on mount)
  return useMemo(
    () =>
      //make a new object from entries
      Object.fromEntries(
        //get object entries from loginActions
        Object.entries(loginActions)
          .filter(
            //only if the property is a function
            ([, value]) => typeof value === 'function'
          )
          .map(([key, value]) => [
            key,
            //create a new function that when called will
            //  dispatch the result of the original function
            //  call
            (...args) => dispatch(value(...args)),
          ])
      ),
    [dispatch]
  );
};
```